# MediaElement.Position behaviour and Windows Phone 7 issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, media, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I have a problem, I have written a simple Media Player for Windows Phone 7 and can Play, Stop and control the Volume of a Video (loaded from a URI) however when I try to set the position, this causes the application to freeze.
I have used both these lines, but either does not work:

```
        Player.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)Position.Value);

        Player.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)(Position.Value));
```

I do have this event handler:

```
    void Player_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Position.Maximum = Player.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
    }
```

And have tried using the Seconds value, casting to Ints etc, however everytime I try to set the Position, the app freezes. The video otherwise plays normally - anyone know what the problem may be here?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is but have you tried getting MediaElement to work correctly in regular Silverlight?  That would tell you whether the problem is specific to Windows Phone 7.

Comment: That is a good point, the video does play but I have not tried it in Silverlight on the desktop - will do that, and try a few more videos just incase this is the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an issue on my machine - if anyone can get a video to seek from a URI on Windows Phone 7 please let me know here what you did to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've posted the link to the answer I provided for you on the Windows Phone Developer Forums so that the community on StackOverflow may find it as well:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/db82a416-8153-436d-99c6-5affd03148ce

Regards,

Richard.

Comment: I got no access to this page. Could you please update your post with the solution.